# What is the 'Māsī Māgama (मासी मागम)', and it's significance?

Tags: belief, festivals, tamil

I recently heard about this festival -  'Māsī Māgama (मासी मागम)' and its currently ongoing celebration. Mostly celebrated in the Tamil Nadu.

Some details maybe found [here](https://festivals.premastrologer.com/masi-magam-puja-vidhi-katha-premastrologer.html) and [here](https://www.bhaktibharat.com/festival/masi-magam)

As per the details in the articles -

> "this festival is celebrated to attain Moksha".

So, what are the official details of this festival, and the associated beliefs and rituals? Which scriptures or texts mention it and its significance, specifically about how to attain Moksha?